# Looking for a book of which I have one chapter about plasmons

Tags: plasma-physics, specific-reference, plasmon

I am looking for a book of which I have one chapter. I tried to find this book by references and by copying the text in the GPT chat however without success.

One chapter was sent to me by a professor as a study aid however he has no idea who the author is.

It is chapter 12 which covers topics related to plasmons.

I don't want to share the link to the document here for fear of being banned for disseminating scientific literature, but it seems crucial to me in order to find the author and the entire book.

https://1drv.ms/b/s!Aj6Ri8zy74dJgrAcF9JvIvQVI6n9Og?e=z1rTus

Comment: You could have answered your own question by simply googling the first words in the chapter: ["The interaction of metals with electromagnetic radiation is largely dictated"](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=%22The+interaction+of+metals+with+electromagnetic+radiation+is+largely+dictated%22)

Answer (score 0):

[Principles of Nano-Optics](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/principles-of-nanooptics/E884E5F4AA76DF179A1ECFDF77436452#) by Lukas Novotny, Bert Hecht.

You can read [a summary of chapter 12 here](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/abs/principles-of-nanooptics/surface-plasmons/1FC0BF9FAD8305148C0F71442B5A9BA3). This is from the 2012 edition so it is slightly different from the 2006 edition you have, but it should be obvious it's the same book.

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much.